# Docker laravel: Connection could not be established with host mailhog

Tags: laravel, docker-compose, mailhog

I have a laravel app that is running via a docker-compose file. Here's the file:

```
version: '3'

    services:

      #PHP and Apache

  site:
    user: 1000:1000
    image: alfasoft/php:7.4.27
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=db
      - WEBWORK_SMTP_SERVER=mailhog
    volumes:
      - './:/var/www/html'
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - mailhog

  #MySQL

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.37
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=pde
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=[...]
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=<password>
    volumes:
      - '../../mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    ports:
      - 3306:3306

  #PHPMyAdmin

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

  #Mailhog

  mailhog:
    container_name: mailhog
    user: 1000:1000
    image: mailhog/mailhog
    ports:
      - 1025:1025 # smtp server
      - 8025:8025 # web ui
```

And here's the mailing variables in my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Now, Mailhog is working fine, and whenever I try to send an email through the Laravel App, I receive it on Mailhog UI as expected.

But if I try to run a `php artisan migrate:status` I get this error:

```
Swift_TransportException  : Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

  at /home/gustavo/Documents/alfasoft/projetos/perguntas-de-especialidade/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:261
    257|         }
    258|         $streamContext = stream_context_create($options);
    259| 
    260|         set_error_handler(function ($type, $msg) {
  > 261|             throw new Swift_TransportException('Connection could not be established with host '.$this->params['host'].' :'.$msg);
    262|         });
    263|         try {
    264|             $this->stream = stream_socket_client($host.':'.$this->params['port'], $errno, $errstr, $timeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
    265|         } finally {

  Exception trace:

  1   Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer::{closure}()
      [internal]:0

  2   stream_socket_client()
      /home/gustavo/Documents/alfasoft/projetos/perguntas-de-especialidade/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/StreamBuffer.php:264

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

And this error also happen when I try to get anything from the Database from Tinker. Any ideas? Every other StackOverflow question I saw so far didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out!

For anyone seeing this later on. I was trying to run the commands from outside the container. Everything was correct and working, I just wasn't running the commands from the right place.